# How to determine value of tension here?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

[image]

The original question is to prove simple harmonic motion of the block but I got stuck in this step.

My attempt:Displacing the block by a distance x which would result result in elongation of the spring by x/2.

The spring force on the pulley is $\frac {kx}{2} $ which is massless.How should I calculate the value of tension here?I can calculate it if the tension is same within all the ropes but I am not sure about that?

Comment: The answer is always the same: **Do a free body diagram for the pulley**. Above you show tensions upwards, but the string tensions are trying to pull the pulley down. Since this is a dynamics problem you need a free body diagram for the mass, as it is accelerating up and down also.

Comment: @ja72 That's the third law in my opinion.I am just not sure whether the tension will be same within all the rope segment then I can use it to calculate the tension

Comment: Go with assume it is not, and see if you are forced to show that it is from the equations of motion. My intuition is that if the pulley has rotational moment of inertia then the force _is  not the same_ on both sides of the pulley.

Comment: @ja72 The pulley is massless so I don't think MOI is necessary here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the two free body diagrams of a displaced pulley.

[image: FBD]

The only assumption here is the if the pulley displaces by $x$, then the mass $M$ displaces by $2x$. This is due to the constant length of the rope. I also I assumed the spring is pre-loaded with $F_0$ in order to support the weight at the equilibrium condition.

I do assume that the pulley has mass $m$, moment of inertia $I$ and the tensions $T_1$ and $T_2$ are not equal. In the end, we can find the conditions that make the two tensions equal if needed.

### Solution Method

**Three equations of motion in total.**

1. Vertical motion of the mass $M$ with displacement $2x$.
2. Vertical motion of the pulley with mass $m$ and displacement $x$.
3. Rotational motion of the pulley with MMOI $I$, radius $R$ and angle $\theta = \frac{x}{R}$.

**Find the spring preload**

By solving the condition where $\ddot{x}=0$ for $x=0$. For this condition you will find $T_1=T_2$ and $F_0 = (m+2 M) g$.

**Three unknowns in total.**

1. The vertical acceleration of the pulley $\ddot{x}$.
2. The tension with the ground $T_1$.
3. The tension with the mass $T_2$.

   The problem is solvable $\checkmark$.

Establish simple harmonic motion *only* if you can rewrite the acceleration in the form of $\ddot{x} =-\omega^2 x$.

Comment: Well, now you know how to solve the general problem, with mass or not for the pulley. Enjoy!

Comment: Why did you take different values of tension here when pulley has mass

Comment: @GENESECT - I did not want to make any premature assumptions. Since it is a dynamics problem some force imbalance is needed to rotate the pulley. (PS. I edited a typo in my solution)